# Retrieve video from server using asp.net mvc webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am doing an application which stores video files in the server. I want to send the video files back to the client using web services. How can I do this using asp.net MVC framework.
I am working on version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your webservice that loads the file to a stream and return the stream.